# Self loop in an undirected graph using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, graphs

How can I create a self loop without a direction on the edge?

```
\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
(3)   edge[loop] node  {$e_{1}$} (3);
```

creates the loop I want but has a direction.

Comment: For the latest version of tikz, this can be done simply with `\Loop[style={}](A)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some reason, the TikZ `every loop` style contains an arrow.
So you simple have to remove that:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every loop/.style={}]
    \node (3) {(3)};
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
        (3)   edge[loop] node  {$e_{1}$} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

or remove it globally with

```
\tikzset{every loop/.style={}}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: ty guys for the fast response :D

Comment: In fact you don't even need the extra `,-` on the edge. `edge[loop]` will suffice if you cleared the `every loop` style.

Comment: @Fritz: Thanks, I forgot to remove that from my first attempt.

Comment: What if I only want to affect an specific loop instead of affecting all loops (i.e. using `every loop/.style`)? Edit: I did it by drawing multiple loops by using multiple `\draw` commands and specifying `[every loop/.style={}]` after the `\draw` command that contains the loop which I want to be indirected. However, I wonder if it is necessary to use multiple `\draw` commands? Isn't there a way for setting the style of a given edge so that using `[every loop/.style={}]` is not necessary?

Answer (score 5):

There is another possibility. `loop` and `every loop` are simple styles and it's possible to redefine  `loop` instead of `every loop`.  It's interesting if you have a lot of loops and if you want some specific options

The code from pgf

> ```
> % Loops
>
> \tikzstyle{loop}=                    [to path={
>   \pgfextra{\let\tikztotarget=\tikztostart}
>   [looseness=8,min distance=5mm,every loop]
>   \tikz@to@curve@path
>   }]
>
> \tikzstyle{every loop}=              [->,shorten >=1pt]
> ```

My modification

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{my loop/.style =  {to path={
  \pgfextra{\let\tikztotarget=\tikztostart}
  [looseness=12,min distance=10mm]
  \tikz@to@curve@path},font=\sffamily\small
  }}  
\makeatletter 

 \begin{document}     
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (3) {(3)} ;
    \path  (3)   edge[my loop] node[above]  {$e_{1}$} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice, can I ask how you would let the loop spurt out on a different direction? (usually I use the grow=left option, but it doesn't seem to work)

Comment: You need to modify some styles like `\tikzstyle{loop left}=   [right,out=15,in=-15,my loop]  `. You need to change `loop left` with  `my loop left` and 'loop'  with `my loop`. Another possibility is to modify and to keep the names `loop`and `loop left`