# Self-loop with tikz-graphdrawing library

Tags: tikz-graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

Self-loop can be drawn on a node; there are plenty of examples in documentation e.g. [tikz: self loop with two arrows at the end (i.e. ending by ->>)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214653/tikz-self-loop-with-two-arrows-at-the-end-i-e-ending-by).

I can achieve it via graphviz easily.

I am using `tikz-graphdrawing` library and I want to draw a self-loop on a node. I tried the following

```
\tikz \graph[ layered layout ] { {1,2} -- n -- n -- {3,4}; };
```

And

```
\tikz \graph[ layered layout ] { {1,2} -- n[loop] -- {3,4}; };
```

[image]

## MWE

```
% Compile using lualatex --shell-escape 
\RequirePackage{luatex85}   
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}

\tikz \graph[ layered layout ] { {1,2} -- n -- n -- {3,4}; };

\tikz \graph[ layered layout ] { {1,2} -- n[loop] -- {3,4}; };


\end{document}
```

Comment: Also you should go back to all your old questions which the community answered for you and accept the best answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}
\tikz[every loop/.style={}] \graph[layered layout] { {1,2} -- n --[loop right] n -- {3,4}; };
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make self-loop without arrow-head? I tried usually style `[--,loop right]` which did not work.

Comment: Found solution to remove arrowhead head: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49149/self-loop-in-an-undirected-graph-using-tikz

Comment: @Dilawar Glad you found it :) Sorry for not responding.