# How to draw a graph in tikz by just giving the vertex set and edge set?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, graphs

I am stuck at the following:

I need to draw a graph G with vertex set V and edge set E.
The set of vertices of G is 1,2,3,4,5,....35,36.
The following gives the adjacency criterion:

```
1 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36

2 is adjacent to the vertices  1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35

3 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 4 5 7 8 10 11 13 14 16 17 19 20 22 23 25 26 28 29 31 32 34 35

4 is adjacent to the vertices  1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35

5 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 16 17 18 19 21 22 23 24 26 27 28 29 31 32 33 
34 36

6 is adjacent to the vertices  1 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 25 29 31 35

7 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 15 16 17 18 19 20 22 23 24 25 26 27 29 30 31 32 33 34 36

8 is adjacent to the vertices  1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35

9 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 4 5 7 8 10 11 13 14 16 17 19 20 22 23 25 26 28 29 31 32 34 35

10 is adjacent to the vertices  1 3 7 9 11 13 17 19 21 23 27 29 31 33

11 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 34 35 36

12 is adjacent to the vertices  1 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 25 29 31 35

13 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36

14 is adjacent to the vertices  1 3 5 9 11 13 15 17 19 23 25 27 29 31 33

15 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 4 7 8 11 13 14 16 17 19 22 23 26 28 29 31 32 34

16 is adjacent to the vertices  1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35

17 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 35 36

18 is adjacent to the vertices  1 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 25 29 31 35

19 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36

20 is adjacent to the vertices  1 3 7 9 11 13 17 19 21 23 27 29 31 33

21 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 4 5 8 10 11 13 16 17 19 20 22 23 25 26 29 31 32 34

22 is adjacent to the vertices  1 3 5 7 9 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 35

23 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36

24 is adjacent to the vertices  1 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 25 29 31 35

25 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 16 17 18 19 21 22 23 24 26 27 28 29 31 32 33 34 36

26 is adjacent to the vertices  1 3 5 7 9 11 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35

27 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 4 5 7 8 10 11 13 14 16 17 19 20 22 23 25 26 28 29 31 32 34 35

28 is adjacent to the vertices  1 3 5 9 11 13 15 17 19 23 25 27 29 31 33

29 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 30 31 32 33 34 35 36

30 is adjacent to the vertices  1 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31

31 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 32 33 34 35 36

32 is adjacent to the vertices  1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35

33 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 4 5 7 8 10 13 14 16 17 19 20 23 25 26 28 29 31 32 34 35

34 is adjacent to the vertices  1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35

35 is adjacent to the vertices  1 2 3 4 6 8 9 11 12 13 16 17 18 19 22 23 24 26 27 29 31 32 33 34 36

36 is adjacent to the vertices  1 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 25 29 31 35
```

**I know how to draw the graph by manually specifying the co-ordinates.
It can be done using `\node` and `\draw`
Is it possible to draw the graph without manually entering the co-ordinates?
Is it possible to make tikz automatically choose the co-ordinates and draw the graph?is it possible to use some loop where I just specify the vertices and edges and the graph gets drawn?**

Since its a big graph its very difficult to manually specify the coordinates.

Please help someone.

Comment: TikZ does have features for automatic positioning of graphs, though I have no idea how to apply your criteria. See chapter 19 *Specifying graphs*, and  Part IV *Graph drawing* of the manual.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.; is it possible to draw a graph in tikz just by specifying the vertices and edges?

Comment: I do believe that is what is described in the manual, yes. But there are various algorithms for the positioning. While waiting for answers, I suggest looking at the manual, or searching this site for examples.

Comment: How do I get the manual? Do you have the link? can you share it pleass

Comment: Texdoc.net(http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), or go to ctan.org. You may also already have it on your computer, as part of the TeX distribution you're using. To find it, open a terminal/command prompt, type `texdoc pgf` and hit enter.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.; thanks for the manual , i just checked it but I could not find how to draw a graph given its vertex and edge set , do you mind sharing the code on how to do it

Comment: I'm not really familiar with this kind of stuff, so I can't just "share the code". What about the example on page 420 in the manual (start of chapter 28)? Beyond that, and searching, I suggest waiting a bit to see if other people will answer, I probably can't. (I may not even have understood your question fully.)

Comment: This looks like another question you've posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552241/how-to-automatically-ask-tikz-to-produce-the-coordinates-and-plot-the-graph-from/552287#552287). I've answered that and have shown you how to relabel the vertices as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%c3%b8rn-t) in the comments, Ti*k*Z has a `graphdrawing` library that can be used to automatically calculate the graph layout.

With `\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}` you enable the graph drawing library. Then you can select several graph drawing libraries with `\usegdlibrary`.

A graph is drawn by giving vertices and their edges in `\graph`. There are several ways to do that, but a simple method (especially if the graph data is computer generated) is to give vertices without connecting edges as `v` and list all neighbours of a vertex that has neighbours in `v--u_1, v--u_2, ..., v--u_n` form.

You have to select a layout from one of the graph drawing libraries you loaded. (A list of libraries can be found in the [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), Part IV).

A self-loop can be drawn with `v--[loop]v`, in my tests `v--v` was not enough (see [Self-loop with tikz-graphdrawing library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375375/35864)).

**You will need to compile the document with LuaLaTeX,** since the graphdrawing library relies on Lua components. (The base graph was generated by the igraph R package for a recent seminar talk of mine, I just added a new node 10 and the self-loop at 1 for this example.)

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{circular,force,layered,routing}

\tikzset{
  graphs/simpleer/.style={
    nodes={draw,circle, blue, left color=blue!20, text=black, inner sep=1pt},
    node distance=2.5cm, nodes={minimum size=2em}
  },
  every loop/.style={},
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \graph[simpleer, simple necklace layout]{
        1--3, 1--[loop]1,
        2--6, 5--6,
        3--7, 4--7, 5--7, 6--7,
        1--8, 6--8, 7--8,
        5--9, 6--9,
        10;
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Erdős--Rényi  graph for~\(n=9\), \(p_{9}=0.3\)
      plus one loop at~\(1\)
      and an unconnected vertex~\(10\)
      drawn in \texttt{simple necklace layout}}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \graph[simpleer, layered layout]{
        1--3, 1--[loop]1,
        2--6, 5--6,
        3--7, 4--7, 5--7, 6--7,
        1--8, 6--8, 7--8,
        5--9, 6--9,
        10;
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Erdős--Rényi  graph for~\(n=9\), \(p_{9}=0.3\)
      plus one loop at~\(1\)
      and an unconnected vertex~\(10\)
      drawn in \texttt{layered layout}}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \graph[simpleer, spring layout]{
        1--3, 1--[loop]1,
        2--6, 5--6,
        3--7, 4--7, 5--7, 6--7,
        1--8, 6--8, 7--8,
        5--9, 6--9,
        10;
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Erdős--Rényi  graph for~\(n=9\), \(p_{9}=0.3\)
      plus one loop at~\(1\)
      and an unconnected vertex~\(10\)
      drawn in \texttt{spring layout}}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Figure 1: circular graph]

---

Here's how you could input your graph (it looks a bit too crowded to be drawn nicely to me, but that may be a matter of taste).

If you have lists of neighbours for each edge, say `v -- {u_1,u_2,...,u_n},`, again loops have to be listed separately.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\tikzset{
  graphs/simpleer/.style={
    nodes={draw,circle, blue, left color=blue!20, text=black, inner sep=1pt},
    nodes={minimum size=2em}
  },
  every loop/.style={},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[simpleer, simple necklace layout]{
  1 -- {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36},
  2 -- {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35},
  3 -- {1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,13,14,16,17,19,20,22,23,25,26,28,29,31,32,34,35},
  4 -- {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35},
  5 -- {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,26,27,28,29,31,32,33,34,36},
  6 -- {1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35},
  7 -- {1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,22,23,24,25,26,27,29,30,31,32,33,34,36},
  8 -- {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35},
  9 -- {1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,13,14,16,17,19,20,22,23,25,26,28,29,31,32,34,35},
  10 -- {1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19,21,23,27,29,31,33},
  11 -- {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,34,35,36},
  12 -- {1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35},
  13 -- {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36},
  14 -- {1,3,5,9,11,13,15,17,19,23,25,27,29,31,33},
  15 -- {1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14,16,17,19,22,23,26,28,29,31,32,34},
  16 -- {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35},
  17 -- {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,35,36},
  18 -- {1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35},
  19 -- {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36},
  20 -- {1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19,21,23,27,29,31,33},
  21 -- {1,2,4,5,8,10,11,13,16,17,19,20,22,23,25,26,29,31,32,34},
  22 -- {1,3,5,7,9,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,35},
  23 -- {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36},
  24 -- {1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35},
  25 -- {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,26,27,28,29,31,32,33,34,36},
  26 -- {1,3,5,7,9,11,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35},
  27 -- {1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,13,14,16,17,19,20,22,23,25,26,28,29,31,32,34,35},
  28 -- {1,3,5,9,11,13,15,17,19,23,25,27,29,31,33},
  29 -- {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,31,32,33,34,35,36},
  30 -- {1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31},
  31 -- {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,32,33,34,35,36},
  32 -- {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35},
  33 -- {1,2,4,5,7,8,10,13,14,16,17,19,20,23,25,26,28,29,31,32,34,35},
  34 -- {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35},
  35 -- {1,2,3,4,6,8,9,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,22,23,24,26,27,29,31,32,33,34,36},
  36 -- {1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35},
  % loops are given separately
  1--[loop]1,
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: full on graph]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but how to compile in `LuaLatex`? I never used it, is it anything that needs to be installed separately

Comment: @Math_Freak Most editors will have a button to run LuaLaTeX. If you normally compile from the command line, just run `lualatex <document>` instead of `pdflatex <document>`. How do you compile your document at the moment? What editor do you use? Note that some changes may be needed if you switch from (pdf)LaTeX to LuaLaTeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28642/35864 (in many cases it is enough to ensure the document is UTF-8 encoded, to remove `inputenc` and `fontenc` from the preamble and change the font setup to `fontspec` (which allows you to load system fonts)).

Comment: I use `TexStudio` and `MikTex`. Where will I write `lualatex document`? In `TexStudio` I just click the `double play` button(green symbol with two arrows) and it gets complied

Comment: @Math_Freak Tools > Commands > LuaLaTeX runs LuaLaTeX on the document. Then you can inspect it by clicking on "View"/F7. (It may also be enough to add a magic command to the top of the document, see the edit.)

Comment: Is it possible to draw the graph without the `necklace` ??

Comment: @Math_Freak You can select a different layout method. See §§30-35 of the manual for different layout options. In my first example I also show `layered layout` and `spring layout`. (For Erdős–Rényi graphs the `simple necklace layout` works quite well I think, but your mileage may vary.)

Comment: For `layered layout` I got the following error message `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/graphs/layered layout' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \graph[simpleer,layered layout]`; Can you please help ?

Comment: @Math_Freak If you want to use `layered layout` you need to list `layered` in `\usegdlibrary`. You'll at least need `\usegdlibrary{layered}`. In general if you want to use a particular layout you always need to load the corresponding graph drawing library under which it is listed/documented in the manual.

Comment: thanks a lot for the clarification